# Alpine.Js - How can i Upgrade

Tags: laravel-8, alpine.js

I am using

https://github.com/laravel-frontend-presets/tall

and unable to upgrade the alpine.js version

I tried changing **package.json**

Changed from

```
"alpinejs": "^2.8.2",
```

Changed to

```
"alpinejs": "^3.1.0"
```

Edit :

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

but alpine.js doesn't work properly

Edited on 25Jun2021
Something like below won't work

```
<div x-data="{ title: 'Start Here' }">
   <h1 x-text="title"></h1>
</div>
```

Edited on 26Jun2021
I tried typing

```
Alpine
```

in the console and it says

```
Alpine is not defined
```

Comment: can you define "doesn't work properly"?

Comment: @Raptor Anything alpine won't work. I updated the question.

Comment: Any errors? Need further debug information

Comment: @raptor I updated the question (Bottom of the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was struggling with this today.

In the **package.json** file you will see alpinejs version 2.x something.

Change this to 3.0.0

```
"alpinejs": "^3.0.0",
```

Now when you run `npm install alpinejs` it will upgrade alpine to the latest version for me being `"alpinejs": "^3.2.2",`.

Finally, you need to open the **resources/js/app.js** file and add the new alpine stuff

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./index');

import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
// Add any extra packages you want to install here
window.Alpine = Alpine

Alpine.start()
```

Comment: If you want to use Alpine version 3 and above as a single bundle without pulling with CDN, after adding the above step to ``resource/app.js``. One last step remains. You need to run ``npm run dev``or ``yarn dev``. Otherwise, it will not compile and reflect the change in ``resource/app.js`` to your application.

Answer (score 1):

I used the CDN and solved the issue.

```
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:This is not a proper solution.**

Answer (score 1):

If you were importing Alpine V2 from NPM, you will now need to manually call `Alpine.start()` for V3. This doesn't affect you if you use Alpine's build file or CDN from a `<template>` tag.

```js
// Before
import 'alpinejs'

// After
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
window.Alpine = Alpine
Alpine.start()
```

https://alpinejs.dev/upgrade-guide#need-to-call-alpine-start

Answer (score 1):

You will need to first go to your package.json file and change `"alpinejs": "^2.0.0"` to `"^3.0.0."` then install alpine using `npm install alpinejs`. This will automatically download the latest version. Then later run `npm install && npm run dev`. Then in your **resources/js/app.js** file, enter the following:

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'

window.Alpine = Alpine
Alpine.start()
```

I struggled with the same. But this worked for me just fine and I believe it will work for you too!